# Using Ajax to reload div Woocommerce Cart Page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce, reload, cart

So I looked everywhere for the answer to this. The closest I ever got was this.

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/

This displays a cart counter with a link to the cart page. This is not what I want. I only mention it because there are many people asking for the code on that link and though the question seems similar, it is not what I need. I am not very familiar with ajax, Wordpress hooks or jQuery but I've been picking up what I can. A simply worded answer would be appreciated. Thanks!

So now,

I have a Wordpress site which works with jQuery so that the user never reloads the page. Content slides in and out. I have WooCommerce set up so that when the user clicks on a cart widget (which displays the number of items in the cart and the total), the cart page containing all the products, prices, thumbnails and checkout buttons slides in. The problem I'm having is that, though the cart widget updates without having to reload (I'm using WP Menu Cart plugin for this), the page itself does not. The cart widget will say "1 item $200" but the cart page will say "your cart is empty".

If I reload the page, the cart page will be updated. I need to update the cart page which is on a div called #cart without reloading the whole page.

Here's the relevant code.

I'm calling my cart page inside the index.php file using this

```
<div id="cart">
<?php 
$id=650; 
$post = get_post($id); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $content;  
?>
</div>
```

I found some jQuery code that should reload the div using .load() but it didn't work. I guess maybe it does work but the content hasn't changed yet so it just loads up the same thing? Here it is. (The first few lines prevent it from reloading the whole page and then do my slide animation.

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {
$('#wpmenucartli').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
sectionsMove($,$('.currentSection'),$('#cart'));


$('#cart').load('checkout.php');

return false;        
});
});
```

I imagine the answer might lie in a better understanding of how and when WooCommerce reloads the cart content but their documentation hasn't yielded any leads.

Again I appreciate the help!